# How do I remap a URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to redirect my URL like facebook in CodeIgniter.

Eg: suppose we give 'example.com/username' then it will display the user profile information.
But my controller is  'example.com/index/username'. here username is parameter.
Here is my controller

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();

        }

public function index($username=NULL) {

     $this->load->view('profile',$data);

 }
```

}

Please help me.

Comment: What happened when you read the manual and tried what it said in there?

Comment: example.com/index/testusername.....this is my url...index is my controller name and testusername is the argument.I need to change this to example.com/testusername.

Comment: Oh OK, in that case what happened when you read the manual and tried what it said in there?

Comment: 404 Page Not Found error

Comment: Ah! Happens sometimes. Here you go http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['404_override'] = 'profile';

class Index extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
}

public function index()
{
    $username = $this->uri_segment(1);

    if (empty($username)) {
        $this->displayPageNotFound();
    }

    // Check if parameter is not a valid username.
    if (!$this->checkIfUsername($username)) {
        $this->displayPageNotFound();
    } else {
       dosomething();
   }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Use 'uri'

```
  //username
    $username = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html